# Insert random NAs in a vector in R as a Loop

Tags: r, loops, random, sample, na

So I have a data frame consisting of values of 0 and 1. I would like to make a loop that randomly samples 38 of those observations and replaces them with NA. I am successful in doing one iteration, where the original vector observations are replaced with the following one line code:

```
foo$V2[sample(seq(foo$V2), 38)] <- NA
```

[image: Data Frame]

However, I would like to do this 20 times and have each iteration compiled as separate columns in a single object. Ultimately, I would have a 20 column data frame with each having 191 observations, each with 38 randomly substituted NA's. At the end of the loop, I would like the data frame to be written out as a text file. Thank you for any help in the right direction.

Data Set:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxfytpfgCdAcdEQ2LWFuVWVqMVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: could you share an example of your data

Comment: Sure! Edited with link provided to data set now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(1998)
foo = data.frame(V2=sample(0:1, 191, replace=TRUE))

# Create 20 samples where we replace 38 randomly chosen values with NA
n = 20 
samples = as.data.frame(replicate(n, {
  x = foo$V2
  x[sample(seq_along(x), 38)] = NA
  x
  }))
```

Then you can write it in whatever format you wish. For example:

```
write.table(samples, "samples.txt")
write.csv(samples, "samples.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you. Second half was what I needed. Worked perfectly.